# Database Query (RoomDB)

Tags: sql, database

I am getting Title and COUNT(isRead) from table notification where isRead=0

It is getting title and isread count for each title. Its fine and returns following

```
Title       count
john          3
denil         4


            @Query("SELECT title,COUNT(isRead)as isRead FROM Notification WHERE 
            pkgName = :packagename and isRead=0 Group By title")
```

but if count=0 , it returns null.

what I need is as following;

```
Title     count
john       0
denil      0
```

how can I do it.???

Comment: Do you mean `sum()` instead of  `count()`?

Comment: No brother.  if count of isread is zero, means nothing is read, then it should return                                                                                                           
           Title count

john 3

denil 4

Comment: Can you add sample data to test against query?

Comment: What database are you using?

Comment: Can you try this?  `select t.title,sum(case when t.isRead = 1 then 0 else 1 end) from Notification t WHERE 
            PackageName = 'test1'  Group By title`

Comment: I have try this, but this does not work

Comment: Select title,SUM (case when isRead=0 then 1 end) as isRead from(SELECT title,COUNT(isRead)as isRead FROM Notification WHERE pkgName = :packagename and isGroup=0 and isRead=0 Group By title)

Comment: both these does not work for me.

Comment: @hassanmirza what doesn't work for you? can you show me your schema and expected result? as I can see you are trying to read from the subquery

Comment: I need      john 0 , denial  0    if query result null

Comment: @Query("SELECT title,SUM(CASE WHEN isRead=0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)as isRead FROM Notification WHERE pkgName = :packagename  Group By title")              This Query Works for me

Answer (score 1):

If you want all data in the table for the package, then move the condition to the `SELECT`

```
SELECT title, COUNT(CASE WHEN isRead = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as isRead
FROM Notification
WHERE pkgName = :packagename 
GROUP BY title;
```

If you want all titles in the table, regardless of package:

```
SELECT t.title, COUNT(n.title)
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT title FROM Notification) t LEFT JOIN
     Notification n
     ON n.title = p.title AND t.pkgName = :packagename AND
        n.isRead = 0
GROUP BY t.title;
```

If you have another table with the list of titles you want, use that instead of the subquery for `t`.